# When is the PTK NP spacecraft likely to be launched?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, russia, human-rating

The [PTK NP](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/acts.html) spacecraft seems to be the future successor of the Soyuz spacecraft. Does anyone know when the first launch will likely be? The estimates I have seen vary a lot, so what will be realistic?

Comment: I'm not sure we can meaningfully answer your question. Roscosmos is notorious for being unpredictable, and even insiders are often kept in the dark by the powers that be (tho you can now find live feeds from web cameras in Vostochny and _see for yourself how its construction is progressing_, courtesy of a curious corruption prevention scheme).

Comment: Link to Vostochny cameras?

Comment: Yeah, I had [a link in bookmarks](http://www.federalspace.ru/21287/) but that has apparently moved and [TSENKI](http://www.tsenki.com/) (Center for Operation of Space Ground-Based Infrastructure) pages are now in Russian only. I'll update my comment when I find them. There are some photos at the bottom of [this page](http://www.tsenki.com/138/).

Comment: Russian only sites is no problem.

Comment: Try [this link](http://oborona.gov.ru/media/video/vostochnylive) but I think you'll need VLC plugin, it doesn't load for me. Or try loading IP cam's stream directly in some player, address shown there is `87.245.169.78:8553` (not sure which protocol, UDP I'd presume).

Answer (score 2):

As for now (April of 2016) the [plans](http://kosmolenta.com/index.php/new-tech/ptknp) are to build the first ship in 2019, launch in 2021.
However, the country's economy is declining with negative forecast, so I highly doubt anything will be launched before 2026.